# How to use curly bracket initializer for a dynamically size array and new?

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

I have a `float*` "array" (not sure if that's the right term for it) that I'm passing to another function. Normally, I would do `float *array = new float[6];` But right now I'm putting in some temporary code, so I would like to set all the values right away. Is there a way I can do something like this:

```
float *array = new float[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

And let it deduce the size, so I don't have to do this:

```
float *array = new float[6];
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
...
```

Comment: `std::vector<float> array{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };` is the C++ way to do it.

Comment: As far as the question goes, you have to specify the size in the new expression.  `new float[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };` -> `new float[6] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };`.  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: And note that this is not the meaning of "variable-length array" in the C++ and C ecosystem.

Comment: It's not a typo, I just didn't know how to do it. I wrote the java way, and if that's the answer to my question then thank you.

Comment: I don't believe that this question should be closed as a "typographical" error because it is a C++20 feature and as such is new knowledge other programmers might be in need of. (I do concede that it would be a "typographical" error in a pre C++20 existence world) @NathanOliver

Answer (score 6):

This syntax is only valid C++20. You have to specify the size of the array otherwise:

```
// error C++17, ok C++20
float *array = new float[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

// ok, any C++ version
float *array = new float[6] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

Of course, the preferred way would be to use a `std::vector` for dynamically sized lists:

```
auto my_vec = std::vector<float>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

If the size is static, always prefer `std::array`:

```
// C++17 syntax
auto my_array = std::array{1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f, 5.f, 6.f};

// C++14 syntax
auto my_array = std::array<float, 6>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

// can't push back into 'my_array'
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Would a pointer be better than a vector if, once the array is made, I never need to change its length?

Comment: @user5074736 In that case a `std::array` can be used. Think of `new` as a low level, expert only operation. Always prefer a container or `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` unless very specific needs.